# Determining if a time series is covariance stationary or a random walk

Tags: time-series, self-study

I don't know how to determine the truth of the following statements regarding this time series model. I know a covariance stationary time-series has properties that don't change over time, but I don't know how to find out if that's true. I also don't know how to determine if a particular series is a random walk with or without a drift.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the following link for better understanding:

https://lectures.quantecon.org/jl/arma.html

Comment: This may be helpful but it doesn't answer the question.